# Adding Action into the DataTables JSON Specific Cell

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am successfully loading JSON data into datatables. But i want to add some processing into specific row. How can I accomplsih this?

1. I want to add a button
2. Use the button to send an row ID retrieved from the JSON object into another page for database processing

Here is my JS:

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('../vendor/process/process_vendor.php', function(response) {
        var vendButton = '<button>EDIT</button>';
        $('#vendorlist').DataTable({
          processing: true,
          data: response,
          columns: [
            {data: "CLIENT_ID"},
            {data: "CLIENT_NAME"},
            {data: "CLIENT_ADDR"},
            {data: "CLIENT_LOC"},
            {data: "CLIENT_PROV"},
            {data: "CLIENT_CONT_PERS"},
            {data: "CLIENT_CONT_PH1"},
            {data: "CLIENT_CONT_PH2"},
            {data: "CLIENT_CONT_FAX"},
            vendButton
          ]
        });
        window.someGlobalOrWhatever = response.balance;
    });
</script>
```

So far the problem is i cant initialize the vendButton and I couldn't retrieve the specific row ID using `CLIENT_ID`:

This is the data from JSON response:

```
[
    {
        "CLIENT_ID" : "CL0000001",
        "CLIENT_NAME" : "ABHIRAMA KRESNA",
        "CLIENT_ENT_DATE" : "12-NOV-14",
        "CLIENT_ENT_SIGN" : "chrishutagalung",
        "CLIENT_CONT_PERS" : null,
        "CLIENT_CONT_PH1" : null,
        "CLIENT_CONT_PH2" : null,
        "CLIENT_CONT_FAX" : null,
        "CLIENT_ADDR" : "JL AMARTA BLOK G NO 10 GROGOL",
        "CLIENT_LOC" : "SOLO",
        "CLIENT_PROV" : null,
        "CLIENT_INIT" : "ABK",
        "CLIENT_NPWP" : null
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`columns` is an object describing **columns model**. You try to simply add a string to it.

Probably, you need to iterate through all objects and add this button to every object.

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('../vendor/process/process_vendor.php', function(response) {
        $.each(response, function() {
            this.vendButton = "<button data-id='" + this.CLIENT_ID + "'>EDIT</button>";
        });         

        $('#vendorlist').DataTable({
          processing: true,
          data: response,
          columns: [
            {data: "CLIENT_ID"},
            {data: "CLIENT_NAME"},
            {data: "CLIENT_ADDR"},
            {data: "CLIENT_LOC"},
            {data: "CLIENT_PROV"},
            {data: "CLIENT_CONT_PERS"},
            {data: "CLIENT_CONT_PH1"},
            {data: "CLIENT_CONT_PH2"},
            {data: "CLIENT_CONT_FAX"},
            {data: "vendButton"}
          ]
        });
        window.someGlobalOrWhatever = response.balance;
    });
</script>
```

This will generate another one column with code like this:

```
<button data-id='123'>EDIT</button>
```

where 123 is `CLIENT_ID` for specific row.

Then, on click, you can simply access it like

```
.click(function() 
{
    var id = $(this).data('id');
});
```

You can also use DataTables API to draw this column programmatically.
Refer to [an official DataTables example](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html).

Comment: So this is what im doing i add id='editvendor' inside the button markup and add this click function, $('#editvendor').click(function(){
            var vendorId = $(this).data('id');
        });     

just above window.someGlobalOrWhatever = response.balance;
and nothing happens. Whats wrong ?

Comment: @KonzMama You shouldn't add the same `id`  for every button. `id` should be unique, selectors by ID return only one element. Make it a class and it will work.